# Создание базы данных с помощью Flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sql

Мне нужно написать базу данных с помощью flask-sqlalchemy, затем из этой базы данных я должен буду отображть данные в html странице (которую я уже сделал). Прошу подсказать, где можно прочитать про создание базы данных и передачу их в html документ с помощью этого фреймворка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я на хабре знакомился, там цикл статей: http://habrahabr.ru/post/193242/

Comment: @WorldCount, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: @Expert, какой вопрос,такой и ответ.